# How do I find the log for the shutdown process?

Tags: macos, shutdown, logs

I've done some Googling and nowhere do I find where you can log the shutdown process.
The best I've found is a log where it states when the shutdown process begins but that's all.

My computer is hanging on the end of the shutdown process and I'm trying to troubleshoot it.

Have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the Console app?

Comment: @zwerdlds Yes, That's where I found this http://d.pr/RETv

Comment: It would be easier to open the activity monitor, search for one with name shudown and kill that process...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the console for the time of shutdown
[image]

In the terminal, go to

```
     /var/log
```

[image]

Find launchd-shutdown.log that was last modified by your system at the time of shutdown and perform a more on it

```
     more launchd-shutdown.log
```

Comment: I found using vim was easier than more but thanks! this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I agree that vim is better for searching through the logs, but for beginners 'more' can be a bit more friendly. (Pun not intended. Don't laugh.)

Comment: For OS X 10.10 Yosemite it's under `/var/log/com.apple.launchd/launchd-shutdown.system.log`.

Comment: @DAKSAjA  - have an upvote... but I cannot find the shutdown log there either, any other possibilities? Could something disable or erase these logs?

Comment: I cannot find the logs in `/var/log` or `/var/log/com.apple.launchd` on macOS 10.12 Sierra. Have these logs been moved?

Comment: The terminal approach is much more comprehensive. For example I did a `grep -r --include="*.log" reboot .` and was able to immediately see what caused the most recent reboot on my mac.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of looking at logs, I would start by booting in verbose mode. (It will also shut down in verbose mode.) Just hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> at boot.

Comment: I was considering do this (except in single user mode since it does verbose too) but I was wondering if I could save the output somewhere so I can research the output.