# MacBook Air (2013) doesn't restart or shutdown after upgrading to OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, shutdown

My MacBook Air (2013) doesn't restart or shutdown from the Finder menu after upgrading to OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I have to press the power button.

Moreover, it shows the Apple logo and progress bar loads for few seconds and then starts normally but could not restart or shutdown.

Comment: By "gage" do you mean spinner or progress bar?

Comment: You probably want to have a look into the LaunchD [shutdown log](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/how-do-i-find-the-log-for-the-shutdown-process/) or did you installed Parallels some time ago? Then take a look at [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6603318).