# MacBook Pro takes 10 minutes to shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro 15", running macOS Sierra, which fails to shutdown properly. Originally when I closed all applications and then went to shutdown, it would take less than 10 seconds to completely power down.

**My problem:**

Now, when shutting down, applications will close properly, the Desktop turns to a black screen (all normal so far) but then the display will not power down, as the backlight remains on. This lasts for anywhere from 9 minutes up to nearly 20.

**What I have tried:**

- I have removed all login items from my user.
- I have done a boot into safe mode.
- I have reset the NVRAM (PRAM).
- I have live-chatted with Apple support and went through clearing the User and System Library/Cache directories.

Nothing seems to resolve the issue.

One point to note is that when I reach the login screen, and choose "Shut Down" instead of entering my user password, it will shut-down quickly. I suspect that an application is preventing the normal shutdown, but don't know how to go about finding it.

I have attempted to look through the console for errors but nothing seems to leap out at me.

Can someone please suggest a solution, or a means to identify what is causing this issue?

UPDATE:
I am just performing the latest macOS 10.12 update to see if that helps at all.

SECOND UPDATE: After using live chat with an Apple engineer, we have narrowed it down to the Launch Agents / Daemons. We moved most of them to the trash, and I have tried to add a few back in (shutdown, reboot and then attempt a clean shutdown). It could be the MySQL agent. I don't have many others apart from Adobe / Creative Cloud, Google's Keystone and Oracle MySQL.

Not sure if I should add this as an answer?

Note: This is not a duplicate as my Mac didn't hang permanently, and the solutions in that question didn't help me in this case.

Comment: Have you tried shutting down after booting in verbose mode? Boot in verbose mode by holding Cmd+V during boot. Once the computer has started up, log in and then shut down. A log will appear while shutting down, which might help to find the issue.

Comment: I booted up and the messages were far too fast to read. Shutting down doesn't show me any output on the screen at all (just black with the backlight on)

Comment: Have you used disk repair from recovery mode? Also, looking through the Activity Monitor?

Comment: Some more suggestions: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/fix-mac-that-wont-shut-down-3597343/

Comment: parsing verbose mode: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/216401

Comment: shutdown log: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/how-do-i-find-the-log-for-the-shutdown-process

Comment: When this happened to my Mac Mini at work, it turned out to be the Google Auto Updater process freaking out. Try the steps [in this article](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/) (and read the comments for additional details) to temporarily disable the updater and see if the long delay disappears.

Comment: have you tried `sudo shutdown now` and seen the same hanging?

Comment: Running that from the terminal didn't make any difference, sorry to say.

Comment: I'd probably try running [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html). This tool often helped me to get rid of diffuse issues like this.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would do is reset the System Management Controller. Do this as follows:

1. Shut down your MBP
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Once you've done that, test for any differences and report back.

**Resetting NVRAM**

You mentioned that you reset the NVRAM. Just in case you weren't aware, resetting this on the late-2016 MacBook Pros is different to all other Macs. The correct process is:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note 1:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Note 2:** These steps will also work to reset the NVRAM (or PRAM) for all Macs. However, the late-2016 MBP models actually required the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys to be held down for 20 seconds, while earlier Macs did not *require* this, but doing so did not cause any problems either.

Comment: The OP has already reset their PRAM.

Comment: @FaizSaleem Yes, but I wanted to ensure they did it _correctly_ as the process for resetting the NVRAM has changed for the 2016 MacBook Pro models. They may have very well followed the correct process, but if they've been a long-time Mac user they may have just assumed it was the same.

Comment: Good point! My apologies

Comment: @Monomeeth do you think resetting the SMC is warranted? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Yes, I do. In fact, I'm very surprised that Apple Support didn't suggest it.

Comment: I'm afraid none of these have helped. I reset the SMC first of all (The apple documentation says to remove the power: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295). I also reset the NVRAM again - held for 20 seconds which actually made 3 chimes just as I left go. Still not shutting down in a timely manner.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove No, please follow my instructions for resetting the SMC. I have no idea what's happened to Apple's instructions, but it appears they've only just been updated (a couple of days ago) and they've got the steps around the wrong way re models with removable and non-removable batteries. I am going to immediately contact Apple about this! Of course, if you prefer not to follow my instructions, I understand. I'll let you know what Apple says about their instructions.

Comment: I had tried your instructions first. I only mention the article because I had to read it a couple of days ago when this issue finally irritated me enough to spend some time on solving it. I will repeat your steps again. I have also updated the question that I am doing a software update.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove Thanks for bringing this to my attention. Apple have raised a ticket to correct the page. I assume we'll see it updated shortly.

Comment: @Monomeeth you're welcome. Thank you for your help thus far. I've added another update to the question.