# How can I get the last logins/shutdowns/restarts located on a volume from another Mac?

Tags: logs

I'd like the `last` command to display login/logout information located on a volume from another Mac. I've mounted that volume at `/Volumes/1013`.

Where does `last` get that information from? I'd rather open the relevant log file and read it directly than use Terminal.

Image added as answer to user nohillside below:

[image]

Solved by Jaume (details below), basically:

sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last -10

works for High Sierra, it didn't work for El Capitan, still very good though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the log for the shutdown process?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/how-do-i-find-the-log-for-the-shutdown-process)

Comment: Couldn't you just go to the same location (/var/log) on the external volume? Nonetheless, it would be good to indicate what you've tried already. E.g. editing your question with a link I gave you and saying that this doesn't help you as it is only for internal volumes would already show that you've did some research.

Comment: What do you mean by "other volume"? Is this volume on another Mac than the one you are currently logged in? Can you remotely log into the other Mac through ssh?

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240690/119271

Comment: not having a good day?, the referenced article doesn’t explain this, not at least for High Sierra.  Yes, I tried that and more, I tried setting cd /volumes/1013/var/log as the working directory and trying last there, and also:
last -10 /volumes/1013/var/log

Comment: It’s pretty clear in my post that I’m talking about volume other than the main system volume, as you can see by  /Volumes/1013/Users/admin

Comment: At the moment we need to guess what you are asking because some crucial details are missing. Can you please add some details about the following: What do you mean by "other volume"? Is this volume on another Mac than the one you are currently logged in? Can you remotely log into the other Mac through ssh?

Comment: Reason we are asking: If the user volumes are just on an external drive the logging still occurs on `/var/log`, independent of the user who logs in. So we might very well miss something crucial about your setup here, so please add some details.

Comment: OTOH, if `/Volumes/1013` is located on another (physical) Mac and just got mounted on the Mac you are sitting in front of you may need to log into the other Mac remotely and access the log there. Or use `last -h HOST`

Comment: @Antonio23249 So you want `last` to read the login/logout information from another macOS volume (mounted at `/Volumes/1013`). The problem is that  `last` can only read a `utmpx` file located in the standard path: `/var/run/utmpx`. There is a nice workaround to get around this limitation, though, use `chroot`. Simply run `sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last -10` and you will get the information you are looking for. No need to write any programs. If your question gets reopened, I'll add this comment as an answer.

Comment: @jaume This question has been reopened

Answer (score 3):

`last` gets its information from `/var/run/utmpx`, a file that records user and tty sessions, shutdowns and reboots on the current system. `utmpx` is a binary file, which means you can't use `less` or `grep` to read it or search for keywords.

So to get the session information of the other Mac, we want `last` to read  `/Volumes/1013/var/run/utmpx`.

Unfortunately, `last` can't be told to read a file different than `/var/run/utmpx`, but this is where `chroot` comes to the rescue. `chroot` takes two arguments, a path and a command, sets the command's perceived root directory to the specified path and executes it.

In our case, this is the command we need (type your login password when asked):

```
sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last
```

This command changes the root directory to point to `/Volumes/1013` so that when `last` reads `/var/run/utmpx`, it actually reads `/Volumes/1013/var/run/utmpx`.

You can pass options to `last`, if you wish, or pipe the output to `grep` for more relevant results, for example:

```
sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last -10 | grep <some user>
```

If the command above doesn't work (for example, you get a segmentation fault), try this:

```
sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ /Volumes/1013/usr/bin/last -10 | grep <some user>
```

that is, run the executable from the other Mac.

Note that there's a limit on how far back you can go with the macOS version with either method.

For example, with macOS "Sierra" 10.12, `last` worked as expected, while with OS X "Mavericks" 10.9, `last` only prints one line and then hangs. `dtruss` shows that a serious incompatibility is the reason for the hang:

```
$ sudo dtruss -p 39542
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available
SYSCALL(args)        = return
dtrace: 3870 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
lseek(0x8, 0x4000, 0x0)      = 16384 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2175 (ID 945: syscall::read_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
```

You can overcome this limitation by plugging the drive to a Mac running an older version of macOS.

For more information on `chroot`, run `man chroot` in Terminal.

Comment: @Antonio23249 Have you had a chance to test the procedure I describe in my answer? I modified the last step, now it should work. I'd appreciate it if you could provide some feedback on it or, if it answers you question, mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: it worked!, at least for High Sierra. Do you know how to get it for other macOS versions such as 10.10, 10.11? I tried for 10.11 and it gave me "Segmentation fault: 11". Thanks a lot, and sorry I took long to answer, I've been so busy.

Comment: @Antonio23249 I'm glad it worked on High Sierra. To get it to work on other macOs versions you need to have a Mac running that OS version, mount the drive and use the `chroot` trick as explained in my answer... it seems that the format of `utmpx` has changed and High Sierra's `last` chokes on an old file from 10.11.

Comment: @Antonio23249 I've realized that the most probable reason for the segmentation fault is not the format of `utmpx`, but shared libraries last is linked to, so disregard my previous comment. Try `sudo chroot /Volumes/<volume name> /Volumes/<volume name>/usr/bin/last -10` and report back (this might work with macOS 10.11 or even 10.10), but be aware that there's a limit on how far back you can go, see my answer for more details, I've edited it to include this and more information.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man last` the relevant information is read from the `utmpx` file which (see `man 5 utmpx`) is stored in `/var/run/utmpx`. So if you are mounting volumes from another Mac on your network **and** the `/var/` hierarchy of said Mac is accessible through the mount point you will find the data in `/Volumes/1013/var/run/utmpx`. Because `utmpx` is a binary format you would need to write your own little program to read it though (see `man endutxent` for the relevant access functions).

You could also try to use the `-h host` option of `last` to read the entries directly over the network (probably requires remote login to be enabled, never have used this and don't have a second Mac right now to try it).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your anwer.  Well, I opened that utmpx for the startup drive and just shows a few lines (please check picture I added to original post).  So you say I'd need to write a program?  Is there now way to use Last and a path or something.  I'm in the process of learning to use Terminal but don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: @Antonio23249 `last` can only read the local file on the standard path. Why can‘t you run `last` on the computer where the file is created?

Comment: @nohillside There is a much easier approach to this: `chroot`. This simple command: `sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last -10` will get exactly the information the OP is asking for (tested with a mounted drive with Sierra on it). I've added a comment to the OP's question with this information, if the question gets reopened, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @jaume Nice one! Question is open again, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks nohillside, that was the one!: sudo chroot /Volumes/1013/ last -10, worked very well, at least for High Sierra.  Do you know how to get it for other macOS versions such as 10.10, 10.11?  I tried for 10.11 and it gave me "Segmentation fault: 11".  Thanks a lot!